# Managing clicked item's props in a new route - React router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a map of an objects. Each object is an item in a list. When I click on a concrete item it moves me to a specific route with that **item's id**. How to properly manage that concrete item's props inside new route?

Is this the way to go or there is better way?

```
export const Router = (): ReactElement => {
  const [itemDetails, setItemDetails] = useState<Item>();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
          <Route
            index
            element={<ItemList setItemDetails={setItemDetails} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/item/:itemId"
            element={<ItemDetails itemDetails={itemDetails} />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

So basically what I'm doing here is I'm passing state setter function to a list where my mapped items are stored so when I click on a concrete one I save its props to that function.

Then I just pass updated state to a new route where details of a concrete item should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if there's a better way than pushing some value from `ItemList` up to the parent state to be passed down to `ItemDetails`, then sure, a more React/`react-router-dom` way would be to hoist the items array from the `ItemList` component up to this parent component and pass the data down to children routes as props or via a context.

### Example using props

```
export const Router = (): ReactElement => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<Item>>([]);

  ... logic to populate items state ...

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
          <Route index element={<ItemList items={items} />} />
          <Route path="/item/:itemId" element={<ItemDetails items={items} />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

ItemDetails

```
const ItemDetails = ({ items }) => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();
  const item = items.find(item => String(item.id) === itemId);

  if (!item) {
    return <div>No matching item found.</div>;
  }
  return (
    ... render item out to JSX
  );
};
```

### Example using Outlet context

```
export const Router = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
          <Route index element={<ItemList />} />
          <Route path="/item/:itemId" element={<ItemDetails />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Root

```
const Root = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<Item>>([]);

  ... logic to populate items state ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet context={{ items }} />
    ...
  );
};
```

ItemList

```
const ItemList = () => {
  const { items } = useOutletContext();

  return (
    ... map items to JSX
  );
};
```

ItemDetails

```
const ItemDetails = () => {
  const { items } = useOutletContext();
  const { itemId } = useParams();
  const item = items.find(item => String(item.id) === itemId);

  if (!item) {
    return <div>No matching item found.</div>;
  }
  return (
    ... render item out to JSX
  );
};
```

Comment: Really like the idea with Outlet context. However i should have specified that im using useNavigate hook and i just got to know there is "options" arg so i can pass there my item props. Anyway, thanks for showing me different way of doing it!

Comment: @Adrian Oh, right, there *is* also the option of passing the item object directly in route state, i.e. `navigate("/item/1234", { state: { item } });` and accessing `location.state.item` in the receiving component. The downside to this though is that the route state is pretty transient and basically only exists for the transition. If you navigate directly to `"/item/:itemId"` outside the `navigate` function the state will be missing. You'll want to keep this in mind if using this method of passing data.

Comment: Ouch, then im gonna definitely switch to that outlet context idea. Thanks, a lot!!